# Do GCC and clang show the same result as Visual Studio on this case, about language linkage?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, linkage

[[dcl.link]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.link#4):

> Linkage specifications nest. When linkage specifications nest, the
>   innermost one determines the language linkage. A linkage specification
>   does not establish a scope. A linkage-specification shall occur only
>   in namespace scope. In a linkage-specification, **the specified
>   language linkage applies to the function types of all function
>   declarators**, function names with external linkage, and variable
>   names with external linkage declared within the linkage-specification.
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> extern "C"                      // the name f1 and its function type have C language linkage;
>   void f1(void(*pf)(int));      // pf is a pointer to a C function
> ```
>
> ...
>
> — end example ]

Observe that the pointer `&foo` passed to the function `c_f()` below is **not** a pointer to a C function. This code compiles and links normally in VS2017. But it shouldn't, according to [dcl.link]/4.

**File** `main.cpp`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C"                          // the name c_f and its function type have C language linkage;
void c_f(void(*pf)(int));           // pf is a pointer to a C function

void foo(int i) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
}

extern "C" void c_foo(int);

int main() {
    c_foo(1);       // Calls c_foo(int) defined in other.c
    c_f(&foo);      // Calls c_f(void(*)(int)) defined in other.c, but &foo is not a pointer to a C function !! 
}
```

**File** `other.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void c_f(void(*pf)(int)){
    pf(2);
}

void c_foo(int i) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

I'm curious to know whether clang and GCC are compliant with the Standard, but I can't verify this in a web compiler.

**Edit**

It dawned on me that I really don't need two files to verify whether clang and GCC are compliant to the Standard, on the issue mentioned above. If the Standard requires the address of a C function, as an argument for the function `c_f()` and the code in `main.cpp` supplies the address of a C++ function, the C++ compiler has to complain<sup>1</sup> when compiling this file. But that doesn't happen neither in [clang](https://godbolt.org/g/VgAkhC) nor in [GCC](https://godbolt.org/g/u22BPG). Then, I might as well say that both clang and GCC are also buggy on this regard.

<sub>1) If we assume that a diagnostic is required</sub>

Comment: *Why* can't you check this with something like godbolt.org ?

Comment: @JesperJuhl How do I insert a second file to be compiled on this site?

Comment: Hmmm, good point :-/ I guess you could always just install clang and gcc and try it out locally then :-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl See my **Edit** above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shows undefined behavior according to [[dcl.link]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.link#1) and [[expr.call]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#1) (emphases are mine):

[dcl.link]/1:

> All function types, function names with external linkage, and variable names with external linkage have a language linkage. [ Note: Some of the properties associated with an entity with language linkage are specific to each implementation and are not described here. For example, a particular language linkage may be associated with a particular form of representing names of objects and functions with external linkage, or with a particular calling convention, etc. — end note ] The default language linkage of all function types, function names, and variable names is C++ language linkage. **Two function types with different language linkages are distinct types even if they are otherwise identical**.

[expr.call]/1:

> A function call is a postfix expression followed by parentheses containing a possibly empty, comma-separated list of initializer-clauses which constitute the arguments to the function. The postfix expression shall have function type or function pointer type. For a call to a non-member function or to a static member function, the postfix expression shall be either an lvalue that refers to a function (in which case the function-to-pointer standard conversion is suppressed on the postfix expression), or it shall have function pointer type. **Calling a function through an expression whose function type is different from the function type of the called function's definition results in undefined behavior** ([dcl.link]). For a call to a non-static member function, the postfix expression shall be an implicit ([class.mfct.non-static], [class.static]) or explicit class member access whose id-expression is a function member name, or a pointer-to-member expression selecting a function member; the call is as a member of the class object referred to by the object expression. In the case of an implicit class member access, the implied object is the one pointed to by this. [ Note: A member function call of the form f() is interpreted as (*this).f() (see [class.mfct.non-static]). — end note ] If a function or member function name is used, the name can be overloaded, in which case the appropriate function shall be selected according to the rules in [over.match]. If the selected function is non-virtual, or if the id-expression in the class member access expression is a qualified-id, that function is called. Otherwise, its final overrider in the dynamic type of the object expression is called; such a call is referred to as a virtual function call. [ Note: The dynamic type is the type of the object referred to by the current value of the object expression. [class.cdtor] describes the behavior of virtual function calls when the object expression refers to an object under construction or destruction. — end note ]